# Update android studio without reinstall

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I saw Android Studio has a Beta version, 0.8.0.

The Android Studio said that the update available, But when I click on download, It takes me to the Android Studio download page.

In earlier updates, They were installed by the software in the background.

I'd like to know how to do it with this version,

Because I already downloaded all the SDK things on the current version of Android Studio, and If i'll download it again, I'll need to reinstall and download all the SDK libraries again.

Thanks.

Comment: Taken from [here](http://tools.android.com/recent).  For various technical reasons we will not offer a patch upgrade from 0.6.1 to 0.8, so you'll need to download and install the full IDE instead.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster Ok, So how to I transfer the SDK?

Comment: If you install it the same way you did for the Preview, you shouldn't need to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install a fresh copy, but you do not need to re-install the SDK, nor do you need to re-configure Android Studio.

**User configruation**

The preview (pre-0.8) stored its user configuration data in `~/.AndroidStudioPreview`, and the beta stores user configuration data in `~/.AndroidStudioBeta`. The first time you launch the beta, it should prompt you to import an existing configuration. Just point it to `~/.AndroidStudioPreview` and it will automatically import your settings.

**SDK**

As for the SDK- you can simply copy the contents of your existing SDK directory to the new default one, create a symlink between the two, or point Android Studio to the old one instead of the new default one.

Simply telling Android Studio to look at the old SDK directory is probably the easiest method. Go to `File > Settings > Default Project Structure`, select "SDK Location" from the left side, and update the SDK path. You may also need to set this for existing projects from `File > Project Structure`.

For me (on Windows 8), the old directory was `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk` and the new directory was `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that after I configured the User Configuration, The SDK directory automatically set!

Answer (score 0):

While you have to install the new Android Studio, you don't need to download the SDK again.  Just point the new installation to the previous installation of the sdk.  In Android Studio, go to project structure and set the SDK Location.